# How do I remove an empty column in a two dimensional list in python?

Tags: python

My python script imports formatted Excel spreadsheets into a 2 dimensional
list. Empty columns can appear at random indexes and I wish to remove all of them.
What would be the best way of doing this?

Any advice is appreciated,

Lou

Comment: A 2-dimensional list is ambiguous. Is it stored row-wise or column-wise? That is, if `L` is your list, and `L[0]` is the first thing in it, does `L[0]` contain a column of data from the sheet or a row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Transpose the array so the inner lists are columns, remove empty inner lists, and transpose it again:

```
data = zip(*data)
data = [x for x in data if any(x)]
data = zip(*data)
```

If it is an issue for the rows to be converted to tuples, replace the last line with the following:

```
data = [list(row) for row in zip(*data)]
```

This is assuming that your inner lists are rows and not columns, if your inner lists already represent a column then you can just do the following (no transposing necessary):

```
data = [x for x in data if any(x)]
```

Comment: This assumes the inner lists represent rows. The wording of the question makes me suspect otherwise, and in fact that a simple check for `[]` in the outer list might be all that is needed. Your answer is definitely right for row-wise, but you may just add what to do for column-wise for completeness.

Comment: As a side effect of zip this also turns the inner elements into tuples (which actually make more sense for representing a row)

Comment: Note personally I'd prefer `data = map(list, zip(*data))` instead of the last line. i like to use `map` if there's a function already defined that does what i want and i don't have to filter

Comment: Updated answer to reflect both the modification from list to tuple, and the column-wise approach.  Thanks for the suggestions.  Regarding `map(list, zip(*data))`, that works fine too I just like to use comprehensions in SO answers so that it will work the same way in 2.x and 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

From the tutorial:

The following list comprehension will transpose rows and columns:

```
[[row[i] for row in matrix] for i in range(lenOfEachRow)]
```

One idea is to transpose it, linearly check each row for all 0s, delete that row (simply using delete[indexOfRow] then transpose it back.

Comment: `zip(*matrix)` will also transpose a 2 dimensional list.

Comment: yes they are equiv. I just took the one directly out of the Python2.7 tutorial.